# How to loop through folder and run code in each pdf with the adobe javascript debbuger

Tags: javascript, loops, pdf, annotations

I have a simple code that adds a freetext annotation to each page on a pdf, the content of the annotations is according to the title.

I run this code on the javascript debbuger inside the pdf, I would like a code to run this code in each pdf in a folder

also for some reason the line "textSize: 26" does not work, It just put the last size used

```
var myname = this.documentFileName

var pos = myname.search("UNIT")
var UnitNum = myname.slice(pos+5,pos+9)
var currentpage = this.pageNum
var AllPages = this.numPages
for(var i=0; i<AllPages; i++){
    this.addAnnot({
        page: i,
        type: "FreeText",
        contents: UnitNum,
        rect: [50,690,70,765],
        Print: true,
        fillColor: color.transparent,
        strokeColor: color.white,
        textFont: font.Helv,
        textSize: 26,
    })

;
}
```